# Group by using linq (range + count)

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, range

```
var data = new[] {
 new { Id = 0, Cat = 1, Price = 2 },
 new { Id = 1, Cat = 1, Price = 10 },
 new { Id = 2, Cat = 1, Price = 30 },
 new { Id = 3, Cat = 2, Price = 50 },
 new { Id = 4, Cat = 2, Price = 120 },
 new { Id = 5, Cat = 2, Price = 200 },
 new { Id = 6, Cat = 2, Price = 1024 },
};

var ranges = new[] { 10, 50, 100, 500 };
```

Needed output is grouped price count by equal or greater than the range used according categories. 
**(in one linq statement)**

```
cat    range       count
-------------------------------------
1       10           2    (In 1. categories there is 2 item that price >= 10(range) [10;30]) 
2       10           4    (In 2. categories there is 4 item that price >= 10(range) [50;120;200;1024]) 
2       50           4    ....
2      100           3    ....
2      500           1    (In 2. categories there is 1 item that price >= 500(range) [1024])
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? If so, please add that code.

Comment: It's not at *all* clear to me what you mean by "by equal or grater than the range used according to categories"

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense.  The total of the count column is larger than the number of items in your example.  Can you explain in more detail exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = new[] {
 new { Id = 0, Cat = 1, Price = 2 },
 new { Id = 1, Cat = 1, Price = 10 },
 new { Id = 2, Cat = 1, Price = 30 },
 new { Id = 3, Cat = 2, Price = 50 },
 new { Id = 4, Cat = 2, Price = 120 },
 new { Id = 5, Cat = 2, Price = 200 },
 new { Id = 6, Cat = 2, Price = 1024 },
};

var ranges = new[] { 10, 50, 100, 500 };

var result = from r in ranges
        from g in data
        where g.Price >= r
        select new {g.Cat, Price=r};

var groupedData = 
        from d in result
        group d by new{d.Cat, d.Price} into g
        select new{Cat=g.Key.Cat, Price=g.Key.Price, TotalCount=g.Count()};
```

Comment: that's not one linq statement

Comment: @pivotnig No, but it can easily be made into one.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
var values =
data.SelectMany(x => ranges.Where(y => x.Price >= y)
                           .Select(y => new { Record = x, Range = y }))
    .GroupBy(x => new { Cat = x.Record.Cat, Range = x.Range })
    .Select(x => new { Cat = x.Key.Cat, Range = x.Key.Range, Count = x.Count()});
```

Results:

```
{ Cat = 1, Range = 10,  Count = 2 }
{ Cat = 2, Range = 10,  Count = 4 }
{ Cat = 2, Range = 50,  Count = 4 }
{ Cat = 2, Range = 100, Count = 3 }
{ Cat = 2, Range = 500, Count = 1 }
```